# Определить что это за кодировка. %s216%t198

Tags: javascript, кодировка

Есть строка в javascript файле

```
this['\x65\x76\x61\x6C'](this['\x64']("%s216%t198%a213%i215%g164%f219%n209%t221%o221%(137%,142%,144%)164%i207%(137%>110%&76%b160%089%{241%a211% 146%=173%a211%s216%F178%o208%t156%a139%b139%,160%=173%a211%s216%I183%t156%b139%,153%=109%,156%=109%,159%=109%,147%=114%,148%=100%l213%k146%+82%b199%z161%+82%z161%,166%=163%u227%c215%i216%n150%n151%{241%a211% 148%=173%a211%s216%I183%t156%n151%;173%e217%u231%n142%t176%n173%+86%t174%t241%;164%f142%l219%c196%t221%o221%.150%o226%t226%a206%e147%i215%d201%x199%f142%h145%=122%-94%)155%e217%u231%n169%f213%r154%i166%092%j167%r161%g162%i165%=167%&76%i165%=177%;164%+86%)164%p173%i149%m170%t161%p156%s176%p154%g146%m153%k168%r161%s174%i207%(155%>123%r155%{235%=173%*149%;168%=170%*149%;157%r215%a204%}250%$76%'74%p220%u232%_134%+143%)87%h220%m217%(162%(152%)82%,80%(79%#144%i215%u232%_134%+143%)87%h220%m217%(162%(149%)82%}250"));
```

И не могу понять, как это закриптовано

```
\x65\x76\x61\x6C - это eval, в юникоде написано как я понял
```

А вот дальше строку, я не могу понять как разобрать...

```
%s216 %t198 %a213 - вот получается из четырех символов состоит 1 буква
```

Comment: А что делает эта строка в JS коде. Что бы оно выполнилось там же где то рядом и дешифровщик должен быть. раз нашли eval замените его на console.log или alert и выполните дешифровщик

Answer (score 2):

- `this` - это `window` или `global` - в общем, глобальный скоуп.
- `'\x65\x76\x61\x6C'` - это `"eval"`
- `'\x64'` - это `"d"`

Получается

```
this.eval(this.d(таБольшаяСтрока));
```

или, в случае браузера:

```
window.eval(window.d(таБольшаяСтрока));
```

Чтобы понять, что делается со строкой, надо смотреть функцию `d`. Сам браузер с "кодировкой" ничего не делает, поскольку это строка без escape-последовательностей.